# Which Pokemon is this supposed to be, Pikachu or Pichu?

Tags: pokemon-series

[image: Pokemon 20th Anniversary Logo]

The 20th Anniversary logo looks like this, and my friend and I had an argument over the identity of this mysterious pokemon. One of us said it is a pichu. The other said it is a pikachu. Which does it more closely resemble but specifically, which is it supposed to be?

Comment: im not realy shure if you are serious or not, since Pikachu is "THE POKÉMON"  it was in there from the beginning and plays a huge part through out the story of Pokémon. Also take note that in the picture are only starter pokemons (some missing) and in the middle is Pikatchu wich is "not a real starter pokemon".... so yes of course its pikatchu

Comment: @GEnGEr Actually, Pikachu was the starter Pokemon in Pokemon Yellow.

Comment: Pikachu is the Pokemon company Mascot and appears in every announcement and advertisement- I think anyone trying to convince you it's Pichu would be a hard sell...

Comment: @nukeforum thats why i sad "not a real starter" in quotation :P but yes your right. But Yellow is a special generation since you cant chose and always start with Pikachu wich i guess leans on the Pokemon TV story ( Manga)

Comment: If you had difficulties identifying this Pokémon among the over 700 existing one, that would've been understandable, but come on... You could've easily found out beyond any shadow of a doubt if this is Pikachu or Pichu, simply by Googling for "Pikachu" and for "Pichu" and comparing the images. That's some serious lack of research effort right there.

Comment: Also, there is a Pikachu dead center of its face which seems slightly larger than the rest...

Answer (score 17):

Looking specifically at the ears, It's definately Pikachu and not Pichu

**Pikachu**

[image]

**Pichu**

[image]

Comment: There's also the color: Pikachu is gold-yellow with bright red cheeks. Pichu is light yellow with pale pink cheeks. The logo is obviously dark/gold yellow and bright red, so it matches Pikachu more than Pichu.

Comment: Just a note: that Pichu is not a common Pichu, but the *Spiky-eared Pichu* :)

Comment: @pinckerman Maybe wasn't the best choice of example picture based on the point I was making ;)

Answer (score 7):

This is definitely Pikachu. The ears are too narrow to be Pichu. The red in the cheeks are also much too dark to be Pichu.

Compare:

[image]

with:

[image]